# Is encrypted database possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, encryption

I'm not a DBA but I've been asked to see if we can encrypt the data in sql server such that the admin, despite having access to SQL Server won't be able to see the data but application would still be able to query on it and read the data.

My limited knowledge of encryption tells me that if application encrypts the data then db won't be able to query it. If db encrypts the data then DBA can definitely read it.

So is there a way to prevent DBA from peeking into data but still be able to manage database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to encrypt the data within the application and store the encrypted values within the database.  Things like TDE and storage level encryption will not meet your requirements.

Comment: But we can't query on encrypted data so that would not be much help isn't it?

Comment: It depends on what data you encrypt.  You have to find a balance between protection and functional.  If you want to prevent the admin from seeing the data the only way to do this would be to encrypt the data within the table at the application layer.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are referring to is [cell-level encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx#_Toc189384683), but using this feature requires changing the application. TDE (transparent database encryption) is another option, this encrypts the files on the disk, but they are decrypted in-memory, so anyone with direct access to the machine and sufficient privileges to look into the block buffer cache directly could access the data.

An alternative approach is to simply use the [db_backupoperator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189041%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) role so the account the DBA uses can backup the database, but has no rights to look at the data. In this scenario, you would want to have the `sa` password written down and locked in a safe in case you ever do really need it.

Tho', as an aside, if you are worried about your DBA stealing your data, your problems are organizational, not technical. I work in a regulated industry myself and DBAs and SAs are carefully vetted (e.g. annual background checks) and we store data in the DB in BLOBs encrypted to which the application has the keys (and no-one has logins on both the machine with the data and the machine with the keys). However, it is possible to take this strategy *too* far. On one of my current projects, I need to use LDAP for authentication. There is some problem, but there is no-one who is allowed to log into both the DB box and the LDAP box, so diagnosing the issue is very difficult - which for the business means, expensive.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer I have used one directional encryption method before. Where application encrypts and stores data in the database ex: password. This was done in a way that even person with access to data can not read the password. Application never needed to do decrypt the password, only encrypt user's input and pass it to database for verification. So in this case it even if we "trust" DBA there should never be a reason for them (or anyone else) to know that information.

But once again this goes to application level and database stays as is.